# Keep getting error class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, class, enums, interface, compiler-errors

I can't see the problem with this short class. I get 8 class, interface, or enum expected errors. Thanks

```
public class BankAccount {
public BankAccount {
    private double balance = 0;
}
public BankAccount(double balanceIn) {
    private double balance = balanceIn;
}

public double checkBalance {
    return balance;
}

public void deposit(double amount) {
    if(amount > 0) balance += amount;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
    if(amount <= balance) balance -= amount;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a modifier and field declared in the constructor. Place it outside the ctor

```
public BankAccount(double balanceIn) {
    private double balance = 0;
}
```

should be

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance = 0;
    public BankAccount(){}
}

public BankAccount {
    private double balance = 0;
}
```

Is also wrong.. it isn't  a constructor you are missing the () and remove

```
private double balance = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the empty set of parenthesis I was missing. Silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet, I normally don't say this but you can accept it as your answer :p